# How to show tick mark on selected picture?

Tags: android

In my app, I am using android gallery to select the picture and show in imageview.
My problem is when I select any picture, I need to show tick mark image on that picture before setting it on imageview.

Following is my code :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
 intent.setType("image/*"); 
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);                     

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
    {
         switch(requestCode) 
         { 
            case SELECT_PICTURE:
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                try {
                    filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    Intent in = new Intent(this,DefaultSubmission.class);
                    if(selectedImagePath!=null && filemanagerstring!= null)
                    {
                        DefaultSubmission.flag = true;
                        in.putExtra("IMAGE_PATH", selectedImagePath);
                        in.putExtra("filemanagerstring", filemanagerstring);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                    finish();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internal error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);}                  
                break;           
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand your question properly, but if your problem is just in drawing a tick above your image, then you need to use FrameLayout instead of a simple ImageView. It should contain your image and a void ImageView above it. When you need to draw a tick - just set its image into that ImageView. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I need to put tick in gallery picture Can u please help me with sample code.

Comment: Sorry, no code to help you. Here's a link you may find useful.
http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect14_d1e13300.html
You need to create an adapter for your gallery, extending the BaseAdapter class. There is a getView() method you need to override. Just create an xml layout containing your FrameLayout and fill it with your data inside the getView(). Please tell me if I did not explain it properly. Good luck!

Comment: What did you try and what was the result?